# Any alternate to slice sling of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a recursive function that adds the two last numbers until there are none left. For example:

```
sumDigits(239)
```

would equate to:

```
2+3+9=14
```

It is difficult because the input must be an integer, which cannot be sliced without converting it. I decided to try to turn it into a lists because I thought the pop() method would be useful for this. It appears as though this approach is not working. Any suggestions?

**EXECUTION:**

```
>>> sumDigits('234')
9
>>> sumDigits('2343436432424')
8
>>>
```

**CODE:**

```
def sumDigits(n):
    l1 = list(str(n))
    if len(l1) > 1:
        a = int(l1.pop())
        b = int(l1.pop())
        l1.append(str(a+b))
        return sumDigits(int(''.join(l1)))
    else:
        return n
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Should `sumDigits(199) -> 19` or `sumDigits(199) -> 1`

Comment: The intended output would be 19

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a string you should pass a list of integers:

```
def sumDigits(l1):
    if len(l1) > 1:
        a = l1.pop()
        b = l1.pop()
        l1.append(a+b)
        return sumDigits(l1)
    else:
        return l1[0]

print sumDigits([2,3, 4])

print sumDigits([2, 3, 4, 3,  4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4])
```

The problem with your approach is that:

`'23434364324|24|'` ->  `'2343436432|46|'` -> `'2343436432 | 10'`,

here now pop will return `0` and `1`,  instead of `2` and `10` as you would've expected. Hence the wrong output.

**Simple solution:**

```
>>> s = '2343436432424'
>>> sum(int(x) for x in s)
44
```

Answer (score 1):

With functional tools like `reduce()` the problem is solved by

```
from functools import reduce

def sumDigits(n):
    return reduce((lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y)), list(str(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The simple solution is:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    return sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
```

Upon your answer of my comment the below solution is not applicable.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    n = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
    return sumDigitsRec(n)

def sumDigitsRec(li):
    if len(li) > 1:
        li[-1] += li.pop()
        return sumDigits(''.join(str(i) for i in li))
    else:
        return li[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since everybody seems intent on solving your homework for you, here's the elegant recursive solution.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return n % 10 + sumDigits(n / 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As strings:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    answer = 0
    for num in n:
        answer += int(num)
    return answer
```

Without slicing, using only an integer input:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    answer = 0
    while n:
        answer += n%10
        n /= 10
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to stop summing the digits when the sum is a 2 digit number. I think the bug in your program is that you need `if len(l1) > 2:` not `if len(l1) > 1:` to make sure you don't recurse when you have just 2 digits.

Comment: No. I want to stop summing when all single digits have been summed. The trick is to do this using recursion

Answer (score 0):

you can do it recursively in this way:

```
def sumDigits(n,s=0):
    if len(n) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return sumDigits(n[:-1],s+int(n[-1]))
```

if you want simpler and pytonic way (not recursive) you can do this

```
>>> s = 2343436432424
>>> sum(map(int,str(s)))
44
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions provided failed to meet the prereqs which were stated in the problem description. This is the correct answer:

**Use **kwargs and exceptions to utilize holding variables in recursion function.**

For example:

```
def recursionFunc(x, **kwargs):
    try:
        count = kwargs['count']
    except:
        count = 0

        #Code down here to add num from x to count
        #remove last index on every iteration from x
        #etc

    return recursionFunc(x, count = count)
```

Answer (score -3):

It's working fine, as the following check will show:

```
>>> 2343436432424 % 9
8
```

If you didn't mean for it to be called recursively then just don't do so, i.e. stop checking the length and just return the sum.

Comment: No, I intended to to add all the numbers as individual digits.

Comment: Your algo will return for 10% of values `0`. It seems broken.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: I didn't supply it as an algorithm, I supplied it as a check.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4: Then, as I wrote, don't call it recursively.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - you have posted an answer so I expected it is related to the question. And your answer is providing wrong results. I was first impress by beauty of your very simple solution, but after quick check it turned out, it is wrong.